# C-library HMAC_MD5 questions

Tags: centos, compiling, c, hashsum

We are working with an older software product that has some limited programming capabilities - specifically, no bit manipulation functions. This has created a significant problem as we need to implement a HMAC-MD5 Hash to interface with an industry standard software interface.

The older software does have the ability to call a C program/dll and pass that information and obtain a returned value.  We have no experience with the C language or how to set up the shared libraries required.

So specifically:

- How should we set up and install a simplistic C compiler environment?
- Where can we find an existing open source C implementation of the HMAC-MD5 algorithm?
- If this does not exist, where can we find a resource to implement this algorithm?
  Our environment is Unix CENTOS 4.9 and Apache/1.3.42

Comment: Is the target platform of the software the same as the development environment?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not respond sooner, this is my fist post on stackoverflow and somehow I missed your response. What do I do next? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler should be `gcc`, If you don't have it, the package has the same name—install it however you normally install CentOS package (e.g., `yum install gcc`)

There are a lot of open source implementations of HMAC-MD5. Any crypto library will have it. And various other projects have one. Google or a code search will quickly turn up thousands.

In fact, HMAC is defined in [RFC2104](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt), which includes example C code in the appendix. (You'll need to grab the MD5 example code from RFC 1321 as well).